# List of completed Pull Request's through Azure DevOps Services Rest Api

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Tyring to use the Azure DevOps Services Rest Api

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

Can anyone suggest the correct API to call to obtain a List of Completed Pull Requests for a Repository

I have been looking at the Git Api, but it seems that particular API only returns PR's that have not yet been completed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This example available on the Rest Api doc site: [Just completed pull requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/get%20pull%20requests?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#just-completed-pull-requests)

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/git/repositories/3411ebc1-d5aa-464f-9615-0b527bc66719/pullrequests?searchCriteria.status=completed&api-version=5.1
```